# Access member variable of C++ object in QML

Tags: c++, qt, object, qml

Is there a way to get access to a member variable of a C++ object in QML? In `main.cpp` I expose an object to QML. How do I access `controller.x` in QML?

```
Controller ctrl;
QQuickView view;
QQmlContext* ctx = view.rootContext();
ctx->setContextProperty("controller", &ctrl);
```

In Controller:

```
public:
 int x;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use property binding, you could do this.

```
class Controller : public QObject
{
  Q_ObJECT

  public:
    Q_INVOKABLE int getX() const { return x; }

  private:
    int x;
}
```

in your QML

```
controller.getX()
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for reply, it is very helpful, but in my Controller i have std::unordered_map<int, ValueReceiver*>, ValueReceiver is a class where i have QtcpSocket and there I have slot start() which connect socket with server. I don't know how connect signal from QML to ValueReceiver from this map.

Comment: You could follow the same approach. may be another question with little code will be helpful.

Comment: In my class : Q_INVOKABLE QHash<int, ValueReceiver*> getQHash() const { return valuesReceivers; } 
In qml i get: Error: Unknown method return type: QHash<int,ValueReceiver*>

Answer (score 6):

Declare the C++ member as a [property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html#qt-s-property-system):

```
class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int x MEMBER x NOTIFY xChanged)

    // ...

signals:
    void xChanged();

private:
    int x;
};
```

You'll need to declare a signal as well, which is what the `NOTIFY` feature refers to. This will let QML know when the value of the property changes:

> A MEMBER variable association is required if no READ accessor function is specified. This makes the given member variable readable and writable without the need of creating READ and WRITE accessor functions. It's still possible to use READ or WRITE accessor functions in addition to MEMBER variable association (but not both), if you need to control the variable access.

Then access it in QML like so:

```
controller.x
```